# Isolated storage is always empty on emulator?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

in my WP7 application, I'm doing :

```
string userName = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("UserName") ? IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UserName"].ToString() : null;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UserName"] = "test";
```

I launch my app (F5), off course, the userName is empty, so it's stored in isolated storage.

I stop my app (stop debugging), and I don't close emulator

Launch again my app (F5), but still empty .

I've read that the isolated storage should persist while the emulator isn't closed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried exiting the app normally? (by pressing the back button in the emulator, not by pressing the 'stop' button in Visual Studio). I think the content of `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` is saved when the application exits. The Visual Studio 'stop' button kills the app, therefore preventing the saving code from running.

Comment: Your right, it's working. In fact, I'm exiting my app by throwing an exception, and I wasn't patient enough to wait for the application to end. Thanks, don't want to answer, then I can mark as answer ?

Comment: Throwing an exception to exit the app? Better remove that before submitting to the MP! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried exiting the app normally? (by pressing the back button in the emulator, not by pressing the 'stop' button in Visual Studio). I think the content of IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings is saved when the application exits. The Visual Studio 'stop' button kills the app, therefore preventing the saving code from running.

Answer (score 6):

You need to also call

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

after you've changed the settings.